# Add Provider Hosted App with App-Only Permission / Policy in SharePoint 2013

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I want to add a "[Provider Hosted App](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx)" in SharePoint 2013 with [App Only Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179892.aspx).

But as soon as I enable "*Allow the app to make app-only calls to SharePoint*" in the App solution in Visual Studio, the app cannot be added with success in SharePoint any longer.
In SharePoint Error Message I got this error:

> "Access required" 
>   "Sorry, you don't have access to this page"

I checked the ULS Log (SharePoint Log), there I saw a "*Claims Authentication*" Error with message (event ID "*g220*"):

> "No windows identity for dom\myusr"

Some other info:

- The user I used is already Site Collection Administrator.
- I do not use any other scope permission in the app.
- I can add the app successfully if I do not enable app only policy checkbox.
- The SharePoint uses claims authentication. And in the ULS Log what I see, that as if it cannot resolve my user because it does not have claim authentication prefix.

**My questions**:

- Have I missed something?
- How can I add the app successfully?

Thanks for any helps!

Best regards

*-motyus-*

---

Detail steps to reproduce error:

1. Enable app only policy in Visual Studio 2012
2. Add and trust the app in SharePoint
3. I got an error message in SharePoint
4. I check in ULS Logs and this is what I got

Comment: The error entry I got in ULS has category "Claims Authentication" with event ID "g220". Message is "No windows identity for {domain}\{username}"

Comment: In SharePoint Error I got this message:
"Access required"
"Sorry, you don't have access to this page"